# Android target: not installed Command failed with ENOENT on ubuntu

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

So I want to create a Cordova app on Ubuntu, I have installed Cordova,Java JDk, android SDK, and gradle
When running Cordova requirements I get error
`Android target: not installed Command failed with ENOENT: avdmanager list target spawn avdmanager ENOENT`

It's my first time creating Cordova app, so I don't know how can I fix this